# android opengl skip faces

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm drawing a simple triangle on a screen. This is my object class:

```
public class GLObj
{
private FloatBuffer     vertBuff;
private ShortBuffer     pBuff;

private float           vertices[] = 
{
     0f,  1f, 0, // point 0
     1f, -1f, 0, // point 1
    -1f, -1f, 0  // point 3
};

private short[]         pIndex = { 0, 1, 2 };

public GLObj()
{
    ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4); // each point uses 4 bytes
    bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    vertBuff.put(vertices);
    vertBuff.position(0);

    // #### WHY IS THIS NEEDED?! I JUST WANT TO DRAW VERTEXES/DOTS ####
    ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2); // 2 bytes per short
    pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
    pBuff.put(pIndex);
    pBuff.position(0);
    // ################################################################
}

public void Draw(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);

    // ### HOW TO PASS VERTEXT ARRAY DIRECTLY WITHOUT FACES?? ###
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_POINTS, pIndex.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

}

My problem is this: to understand OpenGL I want to skip the faces and just display vertices on the screen. The problem is I don't understand how to pass vertices only to glDrawElements function.

Do I 'must' have 'faces' defined (pIndex variable) in order to display vertices even if they're dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need an index array to just draw points. Use `glDrawArrays()` instead of `glDrawElements()`. `glDrawElements()` is for indexed geometry, while `glDrawArrays()` simply draws a sequence of vertices.

In your example, replace the `glDrawElements()` call by:

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.length / 3);
```

Note that the last argument is the vertex count. Since the `vertices` array contains 3 coordinates for each vertex, the length of the array needs to be divided by 3 to obtain the vertex count.